# Show extra form input fields in Joomla 3.x

Tags: forms, input, field, registration, joomla3.0

I am using the registration form default Joomla.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AyCzb2vTaU) and added new input fields in the registration form of Joomla, including radio buttons.

How do I get when the user click the radio button (yes) show additional input fields?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.3+ a showon attribute was added which you can add to any config field you want to hide. In finder you will get this code

```html
<field
                    name="label_pos"
                    type="list"
                    default="left"
                    showon="show_label:1"
                    label="MOD_FINDER_FIELDSET_ADVANCED_LABEL_POS_LABEL"
                    description="MOD_FINDER_FIELDSET_ADVANCED_LABEL_POS_DESCRIPTION">
                    <option
                        value="right">JGLOBAL_RIGHT</option>
                    <option
                        value="left">JGLOBAL_LEFT</option>
                    <option
                        value="top">MOD_FINDER_CONFIG_OPTION_TOP</option>
                    <option
                        value="bottom">MOD_FINDER_CONFIG_OPTION_BOTTOM</option>
                </field>
```

This will show the label_pos field only if the show_label field is set to 1.

So for the four extra fields you can add the showon attribute.  example:

```
showon="show_premium_fields:1"
```